# Fundation Orbit not working JsFiddle

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Why is Orbit from Zurb Foundation not working?
I have included all required files and executed the script?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adam_gajzlerowicz/58og0rao/1/)

I am going by example "content sliders" from here:
[Content Sliders](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html)

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're at least missing the CSS file (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.min.css)

Take a look at the fiddler update (jsfiddle.net/58og0rao/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS to your jsfiddle:

```
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/assets/css/docs.css
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58og0rao/3/